# The even-index reciprocal Lucas constant and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x_1^{2n}+x_2^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, golden-ratio, theta-functions

The [sum of reciprocals of even index Lucas numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalLucasConstant.html) has a nice closed-form in terms of theta functions,
$$\begin{aligned}S_e 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{L_{2n}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi^{2n}+\phi^{-2n}}\\
&= \tfrac14\Big(\vartheta_3^2(\phi^{-2})-1\Big)\\
&= 0.56617\dots
\end{aligned}$$

with *golden ratio* $\phi$ and *Jacobi theta function* $\vartheta_3(q)$.

However, it seems this is just a special case. Given the root $x_1>0$ and $x_2<0$ of the quadratic,
$$x^2+bx-1=0$$

> Is it true that,
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x_1^{2kn}+x_2^{2kn}} = \tfrac14\Big(\vartheta_3^2(x_1^{-2k})-1\Big) $$
>   for ***any*** integer $k>0$, and where the Lucas numbers was just $b=-1$?

Comment: @YuriyS: I was about to make a related edit. Unfortunately, can't figure out how to transform one to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x_1^{2k}x_2^{2k} = (-1)^{2k} = 1$, we may choose $q = x_i^{2k}$ such that $|q| \leq 1$. (For Lucas numbers we have $q = x_2^{2k} = x_1^{-2k}$. But I guess this choice would depend on $b$.) Since $|q| = 1$ case makes the sum diverge, let us focus on the case where $|q| < 1$. Then it boils down to showing

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^n}{1+q^{2n}} = \frac{1}{4}(\vartheta_3(q)^2 - 1 ). $$

It is well-known that $ r_2(n) = \#\{ (a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 : a^2+b^2=n\}$ satisfies

$$ \forall n \geq 1 \ : \quad r_2(n) = 4 \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d \text{ odd}}} (-1)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}. $$

So it follows that for $|q| < 1$,

\begin{align*}
\vartheta_3(q)^2
&= \sum_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2} q^{m^2+n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r_2(n) q^n \\
&= 1 + 4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k q^{j(2k+1)} \\
&= 1 + 4\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{q^j}{1+q^{2j}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I guess it will be hard to generalize this for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\beta_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x_1^{n}+x_2^{n}}$$ for all indices $n$.